# Running Apache/2.4.37 server on port other than 80 with virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.4

So I set up the apache http server on Amazon EC2 Linux 2 machine with 2 virtual hosts.
I can access both virtual hosts and it is working all good on default port 80.

What I wanted to do is run all virtual hosts and main server on other port 8081. When I changed the port in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to 8081 and also in the virtual host files, I can not access virtual hosts through curl command. Connection is timing out. But I am able to do "curl localhost" and get response. So question is why I am unable to access virtual host on port 8081?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to allow 8081 port in inbond rule as well if you want to use that port publicly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow the access of the new port in the security group that this instance assigned to